# How to partition the large JSF pages?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I have one big JSF page containing nearly 1000 lines using normal JSF forms and panelGrids. It would be easier if i keep them in several pages and integrate them as a single page. I would like to know how I can accomplish this in JSF.

I have several forms in that page, in which most of them are `prependID="false"` etc.
Will that affect the flow of the page if I partition the page as several submodules?

I am using ajax extensively and mostly I update one form component from another form component.

Comment: @BalusC that was using Facelets, implemented with JSF 2.0- Mojarra 2.0.2, NetBeans 6.8

Comment: Related: [How to include another XHTML in a XHTML using Facelets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your large page in several files and use <**ui:include**> to merge the blocks.
The <**ui:include**> has no effect on the component tree so this is a pure construction and compositon tool.

```
<ui:include src='part1.xhtml'/>
<ui:include src='part2.xhtml'/>
```

Read the following article to know more about all that:
[JSF 2 fu, Part 2: Templating and composite components](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf2fu2/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for your short and clear answer. I know there is a way to create composite components using NetBeans 6.8. But i dont know how to create this ui:include? I mean, where/how should I define the `part1.xhtml` contents?